# Unmet dependencies while installing albert Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

Am trying to install albert package with `apt-get install albert` but I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  albert : Depends:
libqt5core5a (>= 5.11.0~rc1) but 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 is to be
installed
```

So I tried `apt-get install libqt5core5a` which says the newest version is already installed (5.9.5)

I found the .deb file for 5.11.1 [here](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/cosmic/main/proposed/libqt5core5a) but on installing that I get:

```
dpkg: error processing package libqt5core5a:amd64 (--install): 
package libqt5core5a:amd64 5.11.1+dfsg-7ubuntu3 cannot be configured
because libqt5core5a:i386 is at a different version
(5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1)
```

How to upgrade libqt5core5a version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue by running `sudo gdebi ./albert.deb`

I got the answer from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/864964/635285)

`dpkg` and `apt` for some reason could not resolve or install the dependencies. But `gdebi` did the job.

Comment: @anonymous2 This is a valid answer by OP.

Comment: Fair enough.  Still, it's much better in its edited state than it was before.

Answer (score -1):

There is no package named `albert` in the official Ubuntu repositories, so you must have downloaded it from elsewhere, and it is not compatible with your version of Ubuntu (which seems to be 18.04).

If you want to install this package, you can upgrade your Ubuntu to 18.10; it should work there.

Comment: It will compile properly if libqt5core5a is up to date. My friend is using it in the latest 18.04 Ubuntu that he installed yesterday.

Comment: @ShankarThyagarajan Your friend either is using a different version of `albert` or has done something weird to their 18.04 system, such as installing a 18.10 package on it (which is what you are trying to do now).